# How to render custom handle only?

Tags: layout, xml, update-handle

My handle is **av_paginator_result**

It's for ajax request and it should echo some short result.

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
<av_paginator_result>
        <block type="catalog/product_list" name="root" output="toHtml" template="av/paginator/catalog/product/list.phtml">
            <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar">
                <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
            </block>
            <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>empty</layout><count>6</count></action>
            <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>one_column</layout><count>5</count></action>
            <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_left</layout><count>4</count></action>
            <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_right</layout><count>4</count></action>
            <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>three_columns</layout><count>3</count></action>
            <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
        </block>
    </av_paginator_result>
</layout>
```

I created an observer (controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_after) which is catched by post request:

```
$moduleName = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getModuleName();

        if (Mage::app()->getRequest()->isPost() && in_array($moduleName, array('catalogsearch', 'catalog')))
        {
            $layout =  Mage::app()->getLayout();
            $update = $layout->getUpdate();

            Mage::app()->getLayout()->getUpdate()->resetHandles();

            $update->load('av_paginator_result');
            $layout->generateXml();
            $layout->generateBlocks();

            $products = array();

            $page = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('page', 1);

            $root = $layout->getBlock('root');

            $product_list_toolbar = $root->getToolbarBlockName();

            if ($toolBar = $layout->getBlock($product_list_toolbar))
            {
                Mage::app()->getRequest()
                    ->setParam($toolBar->getPageVarName(), (int) $page);

                $output = $layout->getOutput();
                print $output;
            }
            exit;
        }
```

All these codes work good but if I turn Layout Cache on it doesn't. It always try to generate whole category page, not just a part. Why?

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess but I think there is a cache key which has the same name, so when the cache gets filled, the wrong content is loaded for your request.